# Doctrine composite primary key

Tags: doctrine-orm, composite-key, composite-primary-key

I know Doctrine 2.0 supports composite keys. But I am not quite able to find out what I am looking for.

I have 3 tables => agent, client and client_group.
Agent creates client and client_group. Client_Group has a composite primary key => id, agent_id. agent_id comes from the agent table. While I want the id to be auto incremented, the agent_id comes from agent table.
I am trying to write the yaml files but I am not sure how to specify this agent_id as a primary key in client_group. client_group_id and agent_id are foreign keys in client table. Also, I did read on the Doctrine documentation that composite PK cannot have fields that auto increment.

So I am wondring if I can really do what I am aiming to produce here.

The yaml showing only the relations look like this:

***agent:***

```
  oneToMany:
    client_group:
      targetEntity: ClientGroup
      mappedBy: agent
    client:
      targetEntity: Client
      mappedBy: agent
```

***client_group***

```
  manyToOne:
    agent_id:
      targetEntity: Agent
      inversedBy: client_group
      joinColumn:
        name: agent_id
        referencedColumnName: id

  oneToMany:
    client:
      targetEntity: Client
      mappedBy: client_group
```

***client***

```
  manyToOne:
    client:
      targetEntity: ClientGroup
      inversedBy: client
      joinColumn:
        name: client_group_id
        referencedColumnName: id
    agent:
      targetEntity: Agent
      inversedBy: agents
      joinColumn:
        name: agent_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Any help on this would be aprreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was right there in the documentation. The answer to my question was by using the associationKey.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

If you go down to Dynamic Attributes on the link above, the solution lies there. The limitation however being, I wanted one field of the composite primary key to be auto generated, which I understand is not supported by Doctrine 2.1.

Comment: *"I wanted one field of the composite primary key to be auto generated, which I understand is not supported by Doctrine 2.1"*, that is exactly whay I wanted too... It seems a normal thing to do. For example a user has phoneNumbers, one part of the key is the user_id the other is an auto generated numeric Id value.

Comment: you have to use UUID I guess : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/sharding.html#use-guid-uuids